# RTSP 2.0 adoption and implementation

Tags: implementation, rtsp, rtsp-client

The new [RTSP 2.0 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-rfc2326bis-27) spec tries to solve most of the inter-operaility issues that were encountered in the initial RTSP spec (RFC 2326). Also it provide for means to solve the most dreaded issue - NAT traversal. This has been an incentive for us to upgrade our stack to this newer spec.

I would like to know how many vendors and implementations currently adhere to the new RTSP 2.0 draft. Are there any streaming servers that support this newer spec? Is it really worth the effort to make the upgrade?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GStreamer is one of the first multimedia framework implementing RTSP 2.0 (both client and server)

source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/gstreamer/status/915998393989779456)

Answer (score 0):

In the draft I see @ https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-rfc2326bis-27

It only seems like some additional values are used in some of the headers and other headers have more specific information.

The rest of the changes involve how those headers can be used to shorten the required round trips to the server.

I have my own server implementation @ http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

If you can describe what you wish to support from the draft I will update my RtspServer to have support for it.

You can also make a Thread in the Issue Tracker there to monitor.

If you just wanted to test a few things out you are more then welcome to download the code and  attempt to add support for the new spec.

It seems mostly all of it could be handled in just the RtspMessage classes where obviously the Pipelining stuff would need to be added to the appropriate handlers in the RtspServer.

Nothing seems to complex compared to what it is already doing!

If you need some help let me know!

Comment: My library should be mostly complaint to 2.0, let me know if you find otherwise.